# If $f$ is measurable from $E$ to $G$, and if $g=f$ almost everywhere, must $g$ be measurable?

Tags: measure-theory

Even if this is not generally true, are there special cases of $E$ and $G$ for which this is true?

Answer (score 2):

In general, this is true when the measure is [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_measure).